# Convolution signals and systems

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

given the following signals:

$$   x(t) =
\begin{cases}
A,  & 0 < t < T/2 \\
-A, & T/2 < t < T \\
0, & \text{elsewhere} 
\end{cases} $$

and

$$h(t) = e^{-t}, 0 < t < \infty$$

Then finding the convolution of the two:

$$ y(t) = x(t)*h(t)$$
$$ y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)h(t-\tau)\,d\tau$$

case 1:

$$t < 0 $$
$$y(t) = 0 $$

case 2:

$$t > 0, t < T/2 $$
$$ y(t) = \int_0^t Ae^{-t} e^\tau \, d\tau$$
$$ y(t) = Ae^{-t}\int_0^{t}e^\tau \, d\tau$$
$$ y(t) = Ae^{-t}[e^{t} - 1]  $$

case 3 (this one I'm not to sure of):

$$t > T/2, t < T $$
$$ y(t) = \int_{T/2}^T -Ae^{-t} e^\tau \, d\tau$$
$$ y(t) = -Ae^{-t}\int_{T/2}^T e^\tau \, d\tau$$
$$ y(t) = -Ae^{-t}[e^T - e^{T/2} ]  $$

case 4:

$$t > T$$
$$ y(t) = 0$$

I'm going to upload pictures as soon as I can. Does the following look correct so far? Have to fix it up a bit. Forgot about the boundary for h(t).

Comment: Is $h(t)=e^{-t}$ for *all* $t$, or for $t\geqslant0$?

Comment: Damn, I completely ignored that part. Yeah its $0 < t < \infty$

Comment: That makes the problem much easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $$0<t-\tau<\infty \iff \tau < t <\infty. $$
So for $0<t<T/2$ we $0<\tau<t$ and hence
$$y(t) = \int_0^t A e^{-(t-\tau)}\,\mathsf d\tau = A\left(1-e^{-t}\right). $$
Similarly, for $T/2<t<T$ we have $T/2<\tau<t$, and hence
$$y(t) = \int_{T/2}^t -A e^{-(t-\tau)}\,\mathsf d\tau = -A\left(1-e^{-\left(t-T/2\right)}\right). $$

Comment: Ok thank you very much. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: You're welcome! The trick with these problems is to carefully consider the integration boundaries.

Comment: When T/2 < t < T, this is confusing me. You have positive +A, shouldn't it be -A? And if so, when drawing the functions, the product of the two signals within that boundary looks like it should be 0, since there is no overlap. Could you elaborate a bit for this case?

Comment: Indeed I was missing a minus sign.